# fglrx on Debian stretch

Tags: debian, apt, fglrx

How do I install the fglrx driver on Debian stretch? The [package tracker](https://packages.qa.debian.org/f/fglrx-driver.html) states that there is no package available right now, so I added Sid, pinned on 100. When I try to install  `fglrx-driver` now, `aptitude` returns something about `xorg-video-abi-18`, a package which should be provided by the X server itself as stated [here](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/xorg-video-abi-18).

How is it even possible to not have something as important as a driver in the repository of one of the biggest distros for almost an entire month now?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by downgrading the x-server to the one provided in jessie. The following script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free\n" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stable.list
printf "Package: xserver-*\nPin: release a=stable\nPin-Priority:1001\n" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/xserver.pref
apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade
exit 0
```

To reverse your changes delete the files created in this process.

Please note that I can not guarantee that this will work. You should only do this if you understand what this script will do.

Comment: I would recommend downloading a newer version of fglrx from AMD (as Stephen Kitt suggested) instead of downgrading the x-server. Downgrading x seems more likely to cause other elements of the system to break, especially seeing as stretch has been actually diverging from jessie for over a year since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 6):

The current X.Org server provides `xorg-video-abi-19`, which `fglrx` doesn't support; the ABIs aren't forwards compatible, which is why you can't install the driver from the repositories.

With Debian 9 and onwards, the only way to use AMD GPUs is with the free `radeon` driver (with its companion non-free firmware in `firmware-linux-nonfree`), or for newer GPUs, its successor, `amdgpu` (and on these, you could if necessary use the proprietary AMDGPU Pro driver).

Note that `fglrx` isn't actually part of Debian, it's part of the non-free repository which is hosted on Debian's infrastructure but doesn't receive the same amount of care and support. As far as Debian is concerned, `fglrx` isn't missing from its distribution because it's never been a part of it.

Comment: The drivers direct from AMD do not seem to support the xserver version: "error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.19.2_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.19.2_64a:none:4.9.0-3-amd64:)
Installation will not proceed."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installing open source driver solved my issue (make sure to have contrib and non-free in your source.lst) :

```
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

(the command is coming from the following wiki page : https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo)